# NWPathMonitor detects network disconnect via simulation but NOT via device. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, connectivity

**Scenario:**
   Working with iPad (device) and simulator (Xcode 11.4.1).

```
class ParentViewController: .... {
    ...
    static let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    ...
```

This code works *correctly* via **simulation**.  
When the wifi is disconnected either when the app in the foreground or background, I get the Alert():

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        ParentViewController.monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let self = self {
                    if path.status == .unsatisfied {
                        self.showMissingNetworkAert()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However this *doesn't work* on a **device** (i.e., path.status == .satisfied).

Why???

I consider this is a bug on Apple's part.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you are testing?  I just ran a simple test app on an iPad Pro and and iPhone 8 and it produced the expected results

Comment: I ran thru simulation it worked.   Then tried on device.
On the simulator I disconnect the wifi from the Mac itself (upper left corner).
I had someone offshore try it via device.... didn't get the alert.

Can you send me your test??

Comment: https://gist.github.com/paulw11/0d08de1e8477b9fab09096130bb63492

Comment: Thanks for the link.   I'm suspecting the iPad gives the '.requiredConnection' when loosing the network vs '.unsatisfied' for the simulator.   Because we're not getting the '.unsatisfied' for devices.

Comment: I never saw requiredConnection on the phone or the iPad. Only satisfied or unsatisfied. I tested by both turning wifi on and off and toggling airplane mode

Comment: Is the iPad you are testing with a cellular model with a cellular connection?  Which path were you actually monitoring?

Comment: The official tests were off-shore & in Seattle, WA.
I'm assuming Wifi for both.
I don't have an iPad... So I tested on my iPhone 6s Plus with the latest iOS & Xcode 11.5 Beta 2.   I got 'unsatisfied' when I disconnected my wifi.  The same as via simulator.   Didn't try cellular data.
... this was with your code (added an alert vs label).

Comment: RequiresConnection typically indicates that wifi or cellular Interfaces are available (turned on) but not currently connected to a network. So, it seems like there is a bug in your code somewhere rather than Apple's since my simple example works correctly.

Comment: My same conclusion.   Thanks for confirming this.

Answer (score 0):

You should to add the code below to start monitoring path changes:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")
monitor.start(queue: queue)
```

before

```
monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
                                  ..... }
```